# Time Machine says it must create a new backup erasing my backup history?

Tags: macos, mac, time-machine

Time Machine completed a verification of your backups on “MyBackupDrive”. To improve reliability, Time Machine must create a new backup for you.

What does this mean and why did it happen?

Comment: IS your MyBackupDrive on a NAS?

Comment: [Same question over on Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56063/time-machine-keeps-asking-to-create-new-backup).

Comment: @Nifle - It is on a NAS and it's been working that way for a few months now.

Comment: Seems to be some sort of bug when using Time Machine + NAS. If you google `To improve reliability, Time Machine must create a new backup for you.` you get quite a few hits. I skimmed a few of them but none seems to have a definite solution. So I'm declining to provide any links or answers.